# Can Prometheus scale horizontally with a single data source?

Tags: prometheus

I'm trying to run Prometheus on an unrealistic system (a Raspberry Pi) and I find that it keeps on losing connectivity which I presume is load related.  I was wondering if it can be scaled horizontally by adding more replicas, my experiment is relatively small

```yaml
  prometheus:
    image: quay.io/prometheus/prometheus
    command: >
      --web.external-url=/prometheus/
      --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus
      --storage.tsdb.retention.size=20MB
      --web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries
      --web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles
      --web.enable-lifecycle
    networks:
      - traefik
      - default
      - daemon
    user: root
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /local/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      - prometheus:/prometheus
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 0.5g
        limits:
          memory: 0.5g
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.http.routers.prometheus.rule=PathPrefix(`/prometheus`)
        - traefik.http.routers.prometheus.entryPoints=https
        - traefik.http.services.prometheus.loadbalancer.server.port=9090
        - traefik.http.services.prometheus.loadbalancer.healthcheck.path=/prometheus/-/ready
```

However, when I set to `replicas=2` the second node fails start up because of the lock file so I presume it's not possible to scale horizontally in that fashion.